# How to store the for looped variable to an array?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort the result using the ArraySort() function, the problem is, int cannot be convert to system Array. The code as follows:

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
                Console.Write("{0}" , Array.Sort(a[i]));
            }
```

I have created my own sorting code but, I want to make it shorter than my existing sorting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use LINQ for this:

```
var sortedEvens = from x in a where x%2 == 0 orderby x select x;

foreach (var x in sortedEvens)
    Console.Write(x);
```

Or without LINQ:

```
Array.Sort(a);

foreach (int x in a)
{
   if (x % 2 == 0)
       Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

There is a slight practical difference between the two. The LINQ version leaves the original array untouched, and simply outputs the values in order. the non-LINQ version actually changes the array order.

Comment: I'd love to try that, but, I'm just starting with c# and I have no idea how LINQ works.

Comment: It worked, I knew I should've used the foreach from the beginning but I was reluctant to use it because I never thought that it is possible to sort the array before looping it.